# Swift/IOS: SCNNode appeared to return to its original position after SCNAction is finished, but its actual position was changed by SCNAction

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnaction

I am very new to Swift and IOS development so this could be a simple question, but I struggle to find the answer on the internet.

I was trying to animate a static DAE model by running a SCNAction on one of its nodes. However, after the SCNAction was completed (and the node was moved), the node position will appear to go back to its original position immediately (same position when the static DAE model was loaded). But when I print the node's position, I noticed that the node's position was actually changed because of the SCNAction. And when I ran the SCNAction again on the same node, the node will go back to the end position resulted from the last SCNAction and start the SCNAction from there. I wonder why there's such mismatch between the node's actual position and the position appeared in the scene.

Another interesting thing was when I put SCNActions in sequence ([action1, action2]), the node will not return to its original position between actions. But if SCNAction.wait was added in between ([action1, SCNAction.wait, action2]), the node will return to its original position during the wait, and will start action2 again from action1's end position.

I am trying to maintain the positions of all nodes at the end of SCNActions. Is there any way to prevent it from going back to the original position?

Not sure if the question is clear enough. Any thoughts and ideas are appreciated.

Comment: It seems like there's a simple solution: although the dae model appears to be static, there's an animation attached to it when I got it from Mixamo... After I deleted the 'static' animation in the dae file, everything start to work the way I expect... Guess there's some conflict between the original animation and the scnaction I add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you verified that the node does not come with an animation from the Collada file? Animations and actions are evaluated one after the other. The actions may override the effect of the animation, until they are done (or paused).

Unlike actions, animations don't write in the model tree (`node.position`) but only in the presentation tree (`node.presentationNode.position`).